# Java, SWT: how to make a shell transparent (not alpha!)

Tags: java, swt

how to make a shell transparent? I dont mean the alpha - in other words, I meant "what colors are not need to draw when the shell is being drawn"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to acheive. You cant set "transparent" color in shell but you may use non-rectangular area definfed by Region and have part of your shell transparent. Below is link that is used to comprehend idea:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTShellcreateanonrectangularwindow.htm